# ¿Deberían considerarse como duplicadas preguntas iguales formuladas en diferentes idiomas?

Tags: discusión, duplicados-exactos

Acabo de darme cuenta de que hay dos preguntas iguales en el sitio, con la particularidad de que una está en inglés y otra en español:

- [¿Qué significa “la tercera edad”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3073/12637) (Formulada y redactada en español.)
- [¿Quiénes son las “personas de la tercera edad”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16131/12637) (Formulada en español pero redactada en inglés.)

Acabo de enlazar una con otra, pero no he querido marcar la más reciente como un duplicado, dado que a veces nos hemos encontrado el caso de que una persona no ha entendido una pregunta similar que ya contenía su respuesta por el mero hecho de no estar en su idioma natal. Entiendo que hay personas que están empezando a aprender español y no entienden bien aún las preguntas y respuestas redactadas en nuestro idioma; y a revés, personas que tienen dudas de su propio idioma (el español) pero no entienden las redactadas en inglés por no tener conocimientos de este.

En este tipo de situaciones, veo complejo el llegar a marcar preguntas redactadas en diferentes idiomas como duplicados, y me gustaría saber si podemos llegar a un consenso sobre cómo actuar en este tipo de situaciones. ¿Qué opináis? ¿Se deben marcar como duplicadas o se debe pasar la mano en estos casos?

Comment: Volviendo a la pregunta que desencadenó esta consulta tuya: parece que hay unanimidad, por lo que podríamos marcarla como duplicada.

Comment: @fedorqui sea pues. :-)

Comment: Es interesante ver que en [german.se] tienen una política diferente. En [What to do when the asker cannot understand the duplicate question due to it being in the other language?](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/807/21958) se decidió: _Let me suggest to leave the question open. The question per se may be an exact duplicate but the audience, and hence the answers probably are not_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On [French Language](https://french.stackexchange.com/), we consider [duplicates to be duplicates regardless of the language](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247/cross-language-duplicates-doublons-en-langues-diff%C3%A9rentes).

Given that answers are not always in the same language as the question, it wouldn't really make sense otherwise. If an answer in French to a question in English is legitimate, it's also legitimate for a duplicate question in English.

When we do this, we try to make sure to translate at least the top answers of the original question so that they're available in both languages. (Example: a question in English was closed as a duplicate of [this one](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4481/existe-t-il-des-mots-trop-rares-pour-%C3%AAtre-dans-le-dictionnaire-are-some-words) on 2016-07-24.)

---

En [French Language](https://french.stackexchange.com/), consideramos que [los duplicados lo son indepentientemente del idioma](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247/cross-language-duplicates-doublons-en-langues-diff%C3%A9rentes).

Dado que las respuestas no están siempre en el mismo idioma que la pregunta, no tendría sentido hacer lo contrario. Si es legítima una respuesta en francés a una pregunta en inglés, también es legítimo para una pregunta dupicada en inglés.

Cuando hacemos esto, intentamos asegurarnos de que se traduzcan como mínimo las mejores respuestas de la pregunta original, para que estén disponibles en ambos idiomas. (Ejemplo: una pregunta en inglés se cerró como duplicada de [esta](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4481/existe-t-il-des-mots-trop-rares-pour-%C3%AAtre-dans-le-dictionnaire-are-some-words) en 2016-07-24).

Comment: Fantastic, this makes a lot of sense. When answering, we normally try to stick to the language in which the question was asked; however, these hybrid cases are not uncommon either. Contrary to what I read that happens in [french.se], all regular users in [spanish.se] have a good knowledge of English, so answering in this language is not a problem usually. By the way, I like how you mark translations in French, with a mere line. We tend to mark the language in a very prominent way :D ([example](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2685/1674)).

Answer (score 2):

Let me put a different point of view so that people have something to comment on. Suppose two people ask the same question but one asks in English, the other in Spanish and you have no further information about them from their asking history. Would you necessarily give them the same answer (apart from answering in the language of the question)? I think you might in some cases decide that the focus of your answer might be different as you would assume their background and motivations would be different. I am not saying this would be the case for all such questions but I would not rule it out universally.

Comment: Yes, this is true and would depend on every case. However, to my understanding it is not specifically related to the language in which it is being asked.

Answer (score 1):

¡Interesante caso!

Dado que el usuario medio de este sitio domina el inglés (lengua vehicular de la comunidad) y es un usuario como mínimo competente en castellano, yo considero que dos preguntas con el mismo contenido son duplicadas, independientemente del idioma en que se hayan escrito, pues son entendibles por la mayoría de los visitantes.

La finalidad de marcar preguntas como duplicadas es concentrar el conocimiento. Tener una pregunta igual (o muy parecida) en distintos idiomas solo contribuye a la dispersión, tanto de las respuestas como de los visitantes, por lo que la suma final queda parcheada.

Por tanto, yo sugiero marcarlas como duplicadas (o hacer un *merge* si hay mucha información buena en la marcada como duplicada).

Si alguien quiere, siempre puede actualizar las publicaciones añadiendo la traducción al idioma que falte.

Comment: Las afirmaciones que dependen del "usuario medio" hay que mirarlas con lupa. ¿Qué es el "usuario medio"? ¿Un 51% de los usuarios? Puede haber un 49% que haga una pregunta sin saber (por desconocimiento del otro idioma) que la pregunta ya está hecha. De hecho, ni siquiera lo sabrá porque las sugerencias de preguntas similares saldrán en el mismo idioma en que está redactando la pregunta. Y si alguien lo detecta y se le dice que las respuestas están allí, se quedará sin saber la respuesta por no entender el otro idioma. ¿Tenemos datos oficiales sobre el "usuario medio"?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo el usuario medio es el que define el [tour] y [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic): _Spanish Language Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for students, teachers, and linguists wanting to discuss the finer points of the Spanish language_. Puede que haya muchos visitantes que no encajen en esta definición, pero el objetivo no es abarcar a todos los estudiantes sino centrarnos en los que tengan cierto nivel de comprensión. ... /

Comment: @CarlosAlejo De lo contrario, corremos el [riesgo descrito por uno de los managers de SE](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/a/85/1674): _Once the site devolves into "How do you say 'dog' in German?", you've lost your core audience_.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo sobre la dificultad de encontrar el duplicado, ahí está la importancia de la comunidad: manteniendo títulos claros, etiquetando bien e identificando duplicados. No es motivo de escarnio preguntar una pregunta que ya exista; al contrario, da más vías de entrada al sitio.

Comment: Es un punto de vista interesante y que no había tenido en cuenta. Siempre se me olvida el punto de que el sitio lo definimos nosotros, incluyendo cuál debería ser el público objetivo. Así pues, se espera del usuario medio que se defienda lo suficiente al menos en español, pues el sitio va sobre eso. Luego si no es necesario que sepa inglés pero sí español, ¿qué pasa si la pregunta duplicada se ha hecho antes en inglés? ¿Se marcaría como duplicada la pregunta en inglés a pesar de ser anterior, o la hecha en español a pesar de que el que la hizo no entienda la que está en inglés?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo para elegir cuál es la duplicada y cuál la "original" debería valorarse todo, especialmente la calidad. Después, cualquiera de nosotros puede traducir todo aquello que sea necesario.