# Is it fair to close an English duplicate question where the pointed-to Q-A is in Spanish?

Tags: discusión, votos-de-cierre, idioma-de-la-publicación

This question arises from the discussion about whether to close [Removal of accents from demonstratives](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/30234/9385).

Let's say we get a new question in English about something that's already been asked and answered, but in Spanish.  Is it fair to close the new one as a duplicate?

*Please feel free to write up your opinion about this as an answer -- and then people can indicate their support for one or another answer by voting (and optionally writing comments).*

Comment: Hi aparente and nice to see you debating here. Since you are posting after reading comments, didn't you see mine talking about [¿Deberían considerarse como duplicadas preguntas iguales formuladas en diferentes idiomas?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2524/1674)? It will be funny to mark as a dupe this English question talking about what was already talked in Spanish :D

Comment: @fedorqui - Well, that is interesting.  I didn't notice that.  Now that I've taken a look, I wonder why some were hesitating to vote to close?

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if merging would be better.  But I fear merging would be messy.  Too much work, maybe.

Comment: I also mean _this_ question was already asked in Spanish :)

Comment: @fedorqui - I revamped the question to make it specifically about "Removal of accents from demonstratives."  I haven't figured out why some are still hesitating to close that one.

Comment: It already has 3 close votes, I don't think it will take long to have it closed.

Comment: @fedorqui - Seems to be stuck at 3.